# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'pluginPath' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mailchimp

This is the error message I see in the console when I view my contact form on my Contact Us page here: https://indochinenatural.com/contact-us/

The form doesn't work, because of some Javascript I have loaded in a footer widget.
The form is Contact Form 7 (WordPress plugin).
The javascript is "stock" MailChimp pop-up script.

I am at entry level when it comes to scripts and coding, so if you have any simple advice I would really appreciate it! Thank you

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working for me. I can't reproduce the error and the forms seem to work.

Comment: Which browser? I can't get it to work on Chrome or FF.

Comment: Working for me ... both FF and Chrome (Linux 64 bit)